# undefined index using session

Tags: php, mysqli

hye..im tring to make multilevel login using session..right now i got error undefined index userId in this line..when i tried enter the correct username and password,it does show the alert message and the display the undefined index error

```
if ($data['role' == "partner"]) {

        $_SESSION['partner'] = $data['userId'];
        ?> 
        <script>alert('You are log as industrial partner ...')
        window.location='index.html'</script> 
        <?php
    } else if ($data['role' == "student"]) {

        $_SESSION['student'] = $data['userId'];
        ?> 
        <script>alert('You are log as student ...')
        window.location='index.html'</script>
         <?php
```

where did i wrong..? can someone help me..btw this is my full code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

SESSION_start();
include ('Connections/connect.php');



if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['txtUsername']);
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['txtPassword']);

    if ($username == "" || $password == "") {
    ?> 
    <script> alert('Please enter username and password ...') 
    window.location='mainpage.html'</script> 
    <?php
} else {

     $query = ("SELECT username,password FROM tbluser   WHERE  username='$username' AND password='$password'");
     $result = $mysqli->query($query);
     $data = $result->fetch_array();
     $count = $result->num_rows;

     if ($count>0) {



        if ($data['role' == "partner"]) {

        $_SESSION['partner'] = $data['userId'];
             ?> 
            <script>alert('You are log as industrial partner ...')
            window.location='index.html'</script> 
            <?php
        } else if ($data['role' == "student"]) {

            $_SESSION['student'] = $data['userId'];
            ?> 
            <script>alert('You are log as student ...')
            window.location='index.html'</script>
             <?php


         } else {

            ?> 
             <script>alert('Username or password does not match ...')
            window.location='mainpage.html'</script> 
            <?php

       }

 }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting "username" and "password" from MySQL so `$data` array only contains those two keys.

Comment: ahh my fault..the error is fixed now..but it seems there something wrong with my if else statement..i does't read the statement for student login

Comment: you have a typo if ($data['role'] == "student")

Comment: really? what did i typo..? it seems fine to me..i guess..my eyes maybe did't work properly at 4am..lol

Comment: You have `$data['role' == "student"]`, must be `$data['role'] == "student"`.

Comment: Or in a perfect world `'student' === $data['role']`.

Comment: ahh..ty so much tim..u solved my problem..maybe i should get some sleep and continue this again tomorrow..thnx once again tim